# Unable to post data to Apache tomcat server using POSTMAN

Tags: tomcat, post, server, get, postman

I am trying to post some data to apache tomcat server from POSTMAN. I am able get data from the server but unable to post(the endpoints are different).

For example when I do Get from the endpoint :
`http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/v1/child/140df552-eba9-42c3-8c9e-6d478637925f/learningpods_new/`

But when I am trying to post with some data to the another end point: `http://coreapi.imagin8ors.org:8080/v1/parent/` I get 405 response code(method not allowed).

The HTML response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.9 - Error report</title>
    <style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u>Method Not Allowed</u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u>
    </p>
    <hr class="line">
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.9</h3>
</body>
```

What is the wrong thing I am doing? I am confused because the GET operation gives a 200 status code but POST gives 405.

Is it an authorization problem where you have to give some username:password to post data or some ID is enough??

what is the right way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How have you configured the back end ?

Comment: @wilfredcool007 what do you mean by configuring back end?

Comment: I wouldn't be sure on that, I don't hit the tomcat server quite often but 405 ( method not allowed ) is when the client does not want to accept the incoming request since it has not been configured to accept it ( or my understanding at least ) Whilst I try to figure out, can you see if you can make a HTTPS call rather ? ( sounds absurd, but why not give it a try )

Comment: Ultimately the URL you're using does not accept a POST request.  You should check the documentation to see which URL's accept which HTTP verb (i.e. GET, POST, etc.).  Not every URL will accept any verb as it may be meaningless at that URL.

Comment: @stdunbar thank you. This worked for me(you can write it as answer). I had to change the end point because the given end point doesn't work for PUT/POST. That's the it was configured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on my comment, a particular URL may only have one HTTP verb that it works with.  For example, when getting a web page, the URL might be `/index.html`.  That is a `GET` request and in this example a `POST` may not make any sense for it.

For the HTTP `GET` verb it indicates that the server is giving the client something.  `POST` is a bit of a mix but usually it is the client giving the server something.

In Java code, I may have something like:

```
@Path("/v1/hello")
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
@GET
public Response getHello() {
    return Response.ok("Hello!").build();
}
```

In this example the URL ends with `/v1/hello` to `GET` a simple String.  A `POST` wouldn't work in this case as the code hasn't been defined to handle it.  Here the business rule is that you can only `GET` something from the URL, not give it anything (i.e. `POST` or `PUT`).